# Why do need a separate index in a weak entity?

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship

I am fairly new to SQLServer and there is one thing that really bothers me. Hope one of you guys can explain to me what happens.

When I ran the activity monitor during an indexing process I realized that some queries including weak entities took longer than expected and - even stranger - SQLServer recommended to create an index on the weak entity of the form

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<INDEXNAME>]
ON [dbo].[<TABLE>] ([<ID1>])
INCLUDE ([<ID2>])
GO
```

Doing so (actually I indexed both columns, but I think the result is pretty much the same) really increased the query speed (at least from what I could see in the Activity monitor).

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<INDEXNAME>] ON [dbo].[<TABLE>] 
(
    [<ID1>] ASC,
    [<ID2>] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My question now is: Does SQLServer ignore the clustered index? If yes, why? Can I somehow fix that? It seems pretty strange to me to add another index that should in fact have exactly the same content as the primary key index.

Comment: What is a weak entity? How is it related to NHibernate?

Comment: Since neither the query nor the clustered index is shown, it's kind of hard to figure out if it might be ignored and why. Perhaps the columns are in a different order? You should also use the "show execution plan" features of MS SQL Server Management Studio to explore how the query is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Could be a variety of reasons - show us the definition of your clustered index to clarify.

If your clustered index is on ID2, ID1 and you are selecting both columns in your query but using ID1 in the where clause then it makes sense that this new non-clustered index would work faster.

If you only have the non-clustered index on 1 column but are selecting two columns then it has to go to the clustered index to lookup the data, so in this case adding the second column as an INCLUDEd column or even a second indexed column avoids SQL server having to touch the data pages.

If on the other hand your clustered index is in the same order, it could be any of:

1. FILL FACTOR for your clustered index - if the fill factor is low, the data is spread out over more data pages than needed and it could be slower than reading from a more densely populated non-clustered index
2. The filegroup (and ultimately disk) that your clustered index is placed on - if different, the query optimiser may be identifying high contention or slow seek speeds on the clustered index disk
3. You have been inserting sequential data into your clustered index and the clustered index b-tree is now lop sided
4. Many inserts have occurred to the table, causing many page-splits, causing the data to not be in physical order on the clustered index
5. Your clustered index is not unique - in this case, SQL server will add a uniquifier to your clustered index making it larger, and thus more data to read, and thus slower, than the equivalent non-clustered index
6. Your clustered index is only on 1 column (see below)

If you have your clustered index on 1 column (e.g. ID1), the index data is 2 logical reads into the index but the ID2 column data is on the leaf of the index which is 3 reads deep.

For an equivalent non-clustered index it's only going to require 2 logical reads since it doesn't have to access the data pages, meaning the non-clustered index will be 1/3 faster.

Check out how the clustered indexes and non-clustered indexes are stored:

[Clustered Index Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

[Non-Clustered Index Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Let me know which it was!

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer, I guess it's a little too deep for me though. :)  I guess it all comes down to the question of how I index those tables in an optimal way, assuming there are only very rare write operations and I can reindex whenever I want. My original assumption was that it is sufficient to have the primary key, which apparently is not the case. My next assumption would be to add a 'reverse' index, meaning if the clustered index is [A],[B] to add an index [B], including [A]. Should I then also add [A], including [B]? Are my assumptions totally wrong?

Comment: If you can reindex whenever you want and have rare writes and want optimal reads then create a covering non-clustered index for every query type you have.

e.g. if your query is select A, B, C from tableX where A = ? then create an index on A and INCLUDE the 2 other columsn B and C to make it a covering index.

Comment: To answer your question, your assumptions are just guessing in the dark - your index choice in this case is going to be based on the query types you have. Here's another example - SELECT A, B, C, D from tableX where A = ? and C = ? ORDER BY D DESC.  For this: CREATE INDEX ix1 on tableX (A, C, D DESC) INCLUDE (B)  - note: in this case, you could swap A and C and get similar results - it depends on how SELECTIVE those columns are.

Comment: Thank you Dave, that is pretty helpful! Taking into consideration I have that issue on weak entities I would end up with a maximum of two clustered indexes which is fine. I have only one last uncertainty here: Could there be a performance difference between Index [A],[B] and Index [A] Include [B], Index [B] Include [A]? From your last comment I would assume they should perform pretty much the same.